# rolling standard deviation doesn't work after appending dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, append

I have a big dataframe **temp_history**:

```
Date                Temp
2017-09-14 00:00:00 38.91588479
2017-09-13 00:00:00 38.69563395
2017-09-12 00:00:00 39.25504775
2017-09-11 00:00:00 40.5487144
2017-09-08 00:00:00 41.23372428
2017-09-07 00:00:00 41.5960891
2017-09-06 00:00:00 41.61939397
...
2016-11-30 00:00:00 37.32206175
2016-11-29 00:00:00 36.04661564
2016-11-28 00:00:00 35.70612757
2016-11-25 00:00:00 35.15249571
2016-11-23 00:00:00 36.77833439
...
```

And I have today's dataframe **temp_today**:

```
Date                Temp
2017-09-15 08:59:02 62.85
```

Now I append today's data onto history using

```
temp_history = temp_history.append(temp_today)
```

This gives the **combined dataframe**:

```
Date                Temp
2017-09-15 08:59:02 62.85
2017-09-14 00:00:00 38.91588479
2017-09-13 00:00:00 38.69563395
2017-09-12 00:00:00 39.25504775
2017-09-11 00:00:00 40.5487144
2017-09-08 00:00:00 41.23372428
2017-09-07 00:00:00 41.5960891
2017-09-06 00:00:00 41.61939397
...
```

Now when I try to calculate **7-day rolling std** it doesn't work:

```
temp_history['ST_std'] = temp_history['Temp'].resample('D').ffill().rolling('7D', min_periods=2).std() #rolling 3 mth std
```

It calculates everything but ignore today's appended value in the rolling std:

```
Date                Temp        ST_std
2017-09-15 13:59:02 62.85   
2017-09-14 00:00:00 38.91588479 1.163391429
2017-09-13 00:00:00 38.69563395 1.126344307
2017-09-12 00:00:00 39.25504775 0.83068272
2017-09-11 00:00:00 40.5487144  0.831276056
2017-09-08 00:00:00 41.23372428 1.086552698
2017-09-07 00:00:00 41.5960891  0.93493231
2017-09-06 00:00:00 41.61939397 0.897336665
```

How do I get the rolling std to include today's value as well?

Comment: Is this because of the .resmaple('D') only looks for exactly 24h difference?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i don't have enough reputation points to answer in comment. But could it be the index of each row? Try: ignore_index=True in DataFrame.append

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html